# How to get key and values from a single child using firebase adapter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve both key and its value from "All" and use these to populate my recycler view. How do i do it using firebase adapter. What should be the Model for this?

[image: The image shows the structure of the database]

Comment: You can call `mFirebaseAdapter.getRef(position).getKey();` to get the key.

Comment: and how do i get its child value?

Comment: Use FIrebase-UI recycler view. It handles everything for you

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
    DatabaseReference all = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("All");

    all.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //Loop through all children
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String key = child.getKey();
                String value = (String) child.getValue();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {


        }
    });
```

Comment: I know i can do this, but how to use it in my recycler view?